# Use two 2's, two 1's and two 8's to make the number 2018

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

This is another number formation question. You must use each of $2$, $1$ and $8$ exactly twice to make the number $2018$. The rules are

1. Allowed symbols: $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, $($, $)$, $\sqrt{\quad}$, $!$. Arbitrary functions (such as the logarithm) are not allowed.
2. The ordering of the numbers are not important.
3. It is OK to use numbers as superscript (exponent or the power for the radical symbol).
4. Concatenation is allowed although using $(2+1)1$ to construct $31$ is not allowed.
5. Ceiling or flooring is not allowed. $211\div2=105.5$, not $105$ or $106$.
6. The use of decimal point or scientific notation is not allowed.

   For example,
   $$(2+8)\times(2+1)!\times\sqrt{1+8}=180$$
   is a valid construction, although this is not a solution because it does not equal $2018$.

**Edit** (after slvrbld posted his answer):
Try to make $2108$ and $8102$ as well if you can.

(And of course, the more ways the better).

**Second Edit**
I am thinking whether I can make all 4-digit numbers composed of 2, 0, 1 and 8 (numbers beginning with 0 do not count). I have solutions for some but not all of them. Once I find solution for all of them or find a well defined subset for which I have solutions, I will update it and make it a formal challenge here.

Comment: Was that edit _really_ supposed to say `2108`, or should it just be `2018` ?

Comment: @JPhi1618 The original question is about `2018`, which we already have an answer here. The extra challenges are `2108` and `8102`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Also, note that if you accept an answer, others are greatly discouraged from providing new answers.  If you want more traffic, I'd take back the check mark and only accept after a day or so.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Thank you for your advice. I will take it.

Comment: I don't think you should change the scope of the challenge after you already got a few answers. That isn't fair for the first person answering the question. Instead you could make a followup question linked to this one.

Comment: I have got only one answer when I made the first edit, and I will definitely take that into account when choosing the answer to accept. For edit 2 I will post a new question if I can sort things out.

Comment: Just played around a bit. There is an easy solution to any combination with 0 as last digit, as well as to any combination with 0 as second-to-last digit. The remaining cases seem tough though; I didn't find anything yet.

Comment: With your condition 2 (ordering of numbers not important), do you mean that something that produces (say) 1280 would be acceptable as well? Wouldn't that make the additional '2108' and '8102' challenges redundant?

Comment: @Lawrence there are no digit 0's you can use.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I meant something like "218 * (2 + 1*8) = 2180" - it has all the correct digits, but the order of the digits is different from "2018". Is that also accepted as an answer?

Comment: @Lawrence No, I mean the order of the numbers on the left hand side of the equation does not matter (Some similar puzzles requests that the numbers be in a specific order, like you can only put symbols in 2 1 8 2 1 8=2018, but you cannot swap the order of the numbers. I mean my puzzle is not of this kind). Anyway, 2180 is part of the challenge in my "2nd Edit"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A possible solution:

> $ 1\times2 + 8!/(12+8) $

**Edit:** more obscure approach:

> $\displaystyle\binom{8\times8}{1\times1\times2} + 2 = \binom{64}{2} + 2 = 2018$

Comment: That's a nice solution although I was thinking about something more obscure ...

Comment: Why go for obscure if it can be done in a clean way? :)

Comment: I agree with you, so I think your solution is better than my original one.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, feel free to post your own answer after waiting a little for others to answer.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Sure, but I am just checking whether there are ways to achieve 2108 without using my "obscure" method, so I have edited the question and will wait to see.

Comment: I like that edit.

Answer (score 12):

For 8102:

> $ 8112-8-2 $

For 2108:

> $ 2118-8-2 $

Comment: Most simplistic solution, great.

Comment: You are really quick I must say.

Answer (score 8):

To build up on slvrblds solution by using only the pure numbers (without concatenation):

> $2018 = 2 + 8! / (2 \times (8 + 1 + 1))$

Edit: Got another one with a multifactorial (for obscurity reasons):

> $2018 = 1 + 1 + 8! \times 2 \times 2 \div 8!!!$

Comment: I love this one.

Comment: Yep, nice one. Good usage of the leftover one from my solution!

Comment: The new solution is also beautiful, and includes the element from my intended answer.

Answer (score 1):

First time here :)

> $8! / (18+2) + 2*1$

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but usage of the extra 3 in the superscript is not allowed, and you have three(now four) 2's in the formula while there should only be two 2's.

Comment: Oh, wow I really didn't read that very thoroughly :P

Comment: Never mind, now this one is the same as slvrbld's but it's perfectly OK to keep it as it is.

Comment: Not completely exactly the same. It's 12+8 vs 18+2. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are we restricted to Equations?

Argument:
you need some sort of method to perceive the final result.

The only negative aspect of this answer is that it is not universal.
Blind people would not understand how to read the digit of the final printed number as zero (0).
Mathematics can be used by the blind, Braille is  their chief source of information.

The symbol for 0 (zero) in Braille is a 3 x 2 matrix of:

| 0 1 | 
 | 1 1 |
 | 0 0 |

which doesn't hold up mathematically as in Braille, using the sequence would result in 2818

(see Braille symbols here:  https://www.pharmabraille.com/pharmaceutical-braille/the-braille-alphabet/)

Nevertheless, zero (0) is the absence of any sort of number, so processing this information (even for blind people reading Braille) this can allow for an intuitive understanding of the second digit as the non-integer zero (0 = chaos, absence of comprehensive entity).

Graphical solution using:
http://uniqcode.com/typewriter/

Sequence: 2 1 2 8 1 8
Keypress: 2 back 1 back 2 back 8 1 8

[image]

Lateral Thinking? You could convert to binary I suppose and manipulate them in that manner.
Also, converting numbers to unicode and tweaking them would be an exercise in lateral thinking..

Anyway, I'm not a mathematician but after watching the movie "Arrival" two days ago, I see that skills in linguistics can help decipher 'classical' problems with left-field (right-hemisphere) tactics ;)

Comment: "Are we restricted to Equations?"  Specifically you are restricted to use 6 numbers and the ways you could combine those 6 numbers were specified.  Implicitly the standard meanings of the operators should be used.

Comment: Thank you for your long answer, it provides me some ideas that I can make use of in designing the next puzzles. However I think many of the ideas will be considered too lateral to be suitable for a good puzzle.

Comment: @WeijunZhou  There is no limit to what makes a good puzzle. Nevertheless this puzzle did stoke some dying brain-cells back into life so I'm the one who should be saying thanks. Cheers. ;)