# Use four 8's to make the number 2016

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, formation-of-numbers

Previous question:
[Use two 2's, two 1's, and two 8's to make the number 2018](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59328/use-two-2s-two-1s-and-two-8s-to-make-the-number-2018)

**Background**: I was trying to add some new elements (hopefully creative and interesting) to this traditional type of number-making puzzles, but was clearly beaten by some smart brains which solved the puzzle beautifully without using the intended element. So I am going to make another attempt. I will be happy to see the puzzle solved by traditional ways as well (although @Oray has commented that it is impossible), in which case I am beaten again but I can learn something one way or the other. (I actually have learnt a lot from the answers, thank you all)

**Question**:
I know the year 2016 has passed ... but I am going to publish this riddle anyway because I cannot think of a more elegant one right now. Rules:

1. Use exactly four 8's in the equation, no more, no less.
2. Allowed symbols: $+$, $-$, $\times$, $\div$, $($, $)$, $\sqrt{\quad}$, $!$. Arbitrary functions (such as the logarithm) are not allowed.
3. It is OK to use numbers as superscript (exponent or the power for the radical symbol).
4. Concatenation is allowed although using $8(8\div8)$ to construct $81$ is not allowed.
5. Ceiling or flooring is not allowed. $88\div(8+8)=5.5$, not $5$ or $6$.
6. The use of decimal point or scientific notation is not allowed.
7. The final solution must be an equation. using $!$ to make $!=$ ("not equal to" in some programming languages) is not allowed
8. $+$ or $-$ alone as superscript has different meanings in different contexts. It is not allowed here. Superscript can only be numbers.

Comment: I checked all possibilities with a program code, no answer for 2016.

Comment: @Oray Thank you for your confirmation. That's why I say I want people to jump out of the box (I may just as well have added the `lateral-thinking` tag to the question).

Comment: I did not find a solution for this with four 8's, but incidentally, I found an alternative solution with the conditions of the previous riddle (two 1's, 2's and 8's). I just don't know where to post it.

Comment: @Nebr You can post it on the other question and refer to the comments here, if you wish, so that people won't think you have mistaken 2018 for 2016.

Comment: Yeah, but there it would be misfitting as well. I think it's maybe easiest to do it directly here: The year 2016 is (at least partly) the year 5776 in the Jewish calendar, which is $(8-1)!+((2+1)!)!+8\times 2$.

Comment: @Nebr Interesting and also lateral enough. Thank you very much for your answer. As I have said, I can learn something one way or the other.

Comment: WIth an additional 2, I get this: $\frac{\sqrt{8^8} - 8*8}{2}$

Comment: @SimonMarynissen That's actually something I came across when making this puzzle. Unfortunately I cannot replace the $2$ with a single $8$ easily otherwise we would have had a "four or five" 8's problem. Now I need at least six and I think that's too much for such a puzzle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obscure enough? If this is what you have in mind, then I also know your intended solution for the other problem :).

> $\displaystyle\binom{8\times8}{\sqrt{\sqrt{8+8}}} = \binom{64}{2} = 2016$

Comment: That's great! What do you think the intended answer for the other problem is?

Comment: Check my edit over there and you'll see.

Comment: Yes that's a nice solution, but actually when I wrote down that problem for the first time I was thinking about double factorial :).

Comment: Fair enough. That's even more obscure than what would possibly cross my mind ;).

Comment: Double factorial is a nice idea. I found another solution with a similar approach and edited it into my solution.

Comment: Isn't the binomial an arbitrary function you're not allowed to use?

Comment: @yanko: I thought that too. I assume that because of the way it is written using just numbers and `()` that is bypasses the rule (since other arbitrary functions would require extra characters such as `log` or `e`, etc.). I'm not happy with it as a work around personally but I assume that is the logic.

Comment: @yanko I chose the word "symbols" deliberately, and I use the phrase "you can use the symbol $!$" instead of "you can use the factorial function" deliberately, and I have used points 7 and 8 to illustrate how lateral the solution may possibly be. After saying all these maybe you are still unhappy with it, but that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the part of lateral-thinking or not

> 8! / ( ( 8 + 8 ) / 8 ) = **2016**0
> So we've got 2016 plus 0, but what difference does it make? :)

Comment: Thank you for your interest. It is Interesting, but this is not the intended answer. The intended one is really making the number 2016, not a number that is of the pattern \*2016\*.

Answer (score 0):

> $$8!/((8+8)/.8))$$
>  $$8!/(16/.8)$$ 
> $$8!/(20)$$ 
> $$40320/20$$ 
> $$2016$$

Comment: Nice try, but note point 6.

Comment: :) my bad! almost there

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean any number can be used as superscript in point 3? If so,

> 8!/((8+8^1/3)*(8^1/3))

Comment: I don't mean that, I just mean you can place the number (formed by the existing digits) as superscript.